# Getting System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Tags: apex, unit-test, httpcalloutmock

[image][image]I have implemented everything properly but still I am getting this error. Give you my code for your reference. Please help me.

```java
//code for Combined_Test
@isTest
private class Combined_Test {

    @isTest
    static void testDownloadFileWithMockResponse() {
        // Set up test data
        // Account record
           Account accountRecord = TestUtility.createAccounts(1, true)[0];
            accountRecord.Active_GP__c=TRUE;
            Update accountRecord ;
        //opportunity record
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'OpportunityTest'
                                                    ,CloseDate = Date.today()
                                                    ,StageName = 'New Opportunity'
                                                    ,NS_Stage_OM__c = 'OM Review'
                                                    ,accountId = accountRecord.id);           
            insert opp;

        // Create a test archive file record and get its Id
        archive_file__c testFile = new archive_file__c(Opportunity__c = opp.id, Title__c = 'TestFile');
        insert testFile;

        // Start test and mock HTTP response
       // Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponse());
    
        // Call the downloadFile method from Download_Archive_File class
        Map<String, Object> result = Download_Archive_File.downloadFile(testFile.Id);
        
        // Validate the result or perform additional assertions
        System.assertEquals('mocked_filename', result.get('name'));

       // Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

```java
//Code for Download_Archive_File
public with sharing class Download_Archive_File {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,Object> downloadFile(String fileId){
        List<archive_file__c> files = [
            SELECT 
                Opportunity__c,
                Title__c
            FROM archive_file__c
            WHERE Id = :fileId
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
        ];

        if (files.size()>0){
            archive_file__c file = files[0];
            return gcp_download(file);
        }

        Map<String,Object> noFile = new Map<String,Object>();
        return noFile;
   } 

   private static Map<String,Object> gcp_download(archive_file__c file){
        GCPAuthJWT ga_jwt = new GCPAuthJWT();
        GCP_Key__mdt serviceAccount = ga_jwt.getGCPServiceAccount('archive');
        GCPAuthJWT.GoogleAuthResponse gar = new GCPAuthJWT.GoogleAuthResponse();
        gar = ga_jwt.getGCPAuthToken(serviceAccount);

        String baseUrl = serviceAccount.download_base__c + serviceAccount.bucket__c + '/o/';
        String fileUrl = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(file.opportunity__c+'/'+file.Title__c,'UTF-8');
        fileUrl = fileUrl.replace('+','%20');
        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        system.debug(baseUrl+fileUrl+'?alt=media');
        req.setEndpoint(baseUrl+fileUrl+'?alt=media');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + gar.id_token);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
        blob blobdata = response.getBodyAsBlob();
        String base64data = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blobdata);
        String archiveFileType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
        Map<String,Object> FileData = new Map<String,Object>();
        fileData.put('data',base64data);
        fileData.put('name',file.Title__c);
        fileData.put('type',archiveFileType);
        return fileData;
   }
}
```

```java
// code for GCPAuthJWT
public with sharing class GCPAuthJWT{

    // Class to deserialise response from the Google token URL and get the
    // ID Token
    public class GoogleAuthResponse {
        public String id_token;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Get GCP service account keys from metadata
     * @return the metadata record for the GCP service account
     */
    public GCP_Key__mdt getGCPServiceAccount(String functionName) {
        List<GCP_Key__mdt> gcp_sa_keys = new List<GCP_Key__mdt>();
        gcp_sa_keys = [SELECT
            client_email__c,
            audience__c,
            download_base__c,
            bucket__c,
            token_endpoint__c
            FROM GCP_Key__mdt
            WHERE function_name__c =: functionName];
            
        System.debug('getGCPServiceAccount: ' + gcp_sa_keys);    

        if (gcp_sa_keys.size() > 0) {
            return gcp_sa_keys[0];
        } else {
            throw new GCPException('Cannot find GCP Service Account Keys');
        }
    }
    
    private static String getIssueTime() {
        Long timeSince = System.now().getTime();
        String iatTime = String.valueOf(timeSince);
        return iatTime;
    }

    private static String getExpirationTime(String issueTime) {
        Long longIssueTime = Long.valueOf(issueTime);
        String expTime = String.valueOf(longIssueTime - 3600);
        return expTime;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs the JWT and invokes the Google Auth endpoint
     * @param serviceAccount has the GCP keys obtained from the
     * custom metadata object
     * @return the auth response from GCP containing the id token
     */
    public GoogleAuthResponse getGCPAuthToken(GCP_Key__mdt serviceAccount) {

        GoogleAuthResponse result = new GoogleAuthResponse();

        String issueTime = getIssueTime();
        String expirationTime = getExpirationTime(issueTime);

        Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
        jwt.setAud(serviceAccount.token_endpoint__c);
        jwt.setIss(serviceAccount.client_email__c);
        
        System.debug('getGCPAuthToken jwt: ' + jwt);

        // Additional claims to set scope
        Map<String, Object> claims = new Map<String, Object>();

        System.debug(serviceAccount.audience__c);

        claims.put('scope', serviceAccount.audience__c);
        claims.put('iat', issueTime);
        claims.put('exp', expirationTime);
        
        jwt.setAdditionalClaims(claims);

        // Create the object that signs the JWT bearer token
        Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'google_cloud');

        // Get the resulting JWS in case debugging is required
        String token = jws.getCompactSerialization();

        // Set the token endpoint that the JWT bearer token is posted to
        String tokenEndpoint = serviceAccount.token_endpoint__c;

        Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange bearer = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange(tokenEndpoint, jws);
        String accessToken = bearer.getAccessToken();

        if(accessToken != null) {
            result.id_token = accessToken;
        }

        return result;
    }    
    
    
    public class GCPException extends Exception {}    

}
```

```java
//Code for MockHttpResponse
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Create a mock class for the HTTP callout
    private Integer calloutCounter = 0;

    // Implement the respond method to return different responses based on the calloutCounter
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        calloutCounter++;

        HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setStatusCode(200);

        if (calloutCounter == 1) {
            // First response for GCPAuthJWT class call
            res.setBody('{"id_token": "mocked_id_token"}');
        } else if (calloutCounter == 2) {
            // Second response for GCPAuthJWT class call
            res.setBody('{"data": "mocked_base64_data", "name": "mocked_filename", "type": "mocked_content_type"}');
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

On executing Combined_Test I get the error

Comment: At first blush, this does look correct. Please [edit] your question to include the stack trace for the error you're getting. Knowing the specific line(s) of code that cause the error here is going to be useful information.

Comment: @DerekF in gcp_download we are making two callouts basically, first getting auth code and then making another HTTP callout. Can this be the cause of that error ? Can we try segregating that logic somewhere else and then just passing auth code to gcp_download method ? Maybe this nested callout is causing issue ?

Comment: I can see that, I've read your code. That's not what I'm asking for. Again, please [edit] your question to include the stack trace for your error.

Comment: @DerekF, done that. We do not see anything in stack trace while executing on dev console. Let me know if you need apex execution logs.

Comment: That's not the stack trace. The stack trace says things like "className.methodName line 64". It literally tells you what line(s) led up to the error. You should look at the debug log for your test run and scroll all the way to the bottom. You can then scroll up until you see the error in the logs.

Comment: @DerekF sorry for bothering. Added that. Can you check now ?

Comment: Removing your code after you get your answer is not how this site works. In a way, keeping your code here is the "payment" for asking for help. The questions and answers here aren't just for your own benefit. The purpose of this site is to act as a library of community knowledge; so that other people with similar problems can overcome their own issues (and hopefully learn/grow as a professional).

Answer (score 4):

After learning that this failure is being caused by

```
Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange bearer = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange(tokenEndpoint, jws);
String accessToken = bearer.getAccessToken();
```

It was a simple search to find [this SFSE question from 2019](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174406/how-do-you-use-a-mock-response-when-calling-auth-jwtbearertokenexchange-getacces).

In a nutshell, the `HttpCalloutMock` interface doesn't get used when using the `JWTBearerTokenExchange` class. You need to either wrap the `String accessToken = bearer.getAccessToken();` line inside of a `if(!Test.isRunningTest())` or [use the Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.248.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) to mock the `Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange` class.

There is [an idea to improve the testability of Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcXHUAZ/ability-to-unit-test-authjwtbearertokenexchangegetaccesstoken) that could use some additional attention (though it's still 5 years short of the minimum of 10 years we usually joke that it takes for Salesforce to actually deliver on an idea).

Comment: Thank you so much Derek!

Comment: Does Stub API allow mocking of system classes like Auth.XXX?  I would have wrapped Auth.XXX in a service class and then mocked the service class

Comment: @cropredy Docs mention it doesn't work for system classes, but it's in the `Auth` namespace, so /shrug? Maybe the "mocked class needs to be in the same namespace as the call to `Test.createStub()`" disqualifies _every_ other namespace?

Comment: that is what I always thought -- otherwise we'd have seen more exploitation of this